# HGST hard drive SMART reporting drive failure in less than 24 hours from 1 reallocated sector

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

It says the worst was 1 Reallocated Sector Count and the current is 1 with 5 as the threshold.  That's from smartmontools.  Ubuntu's gnome-disk-manager says almost the same thing but shows the current value at 0.

No other attributes show failing status.

When I noticed this a few days ago, i reformatted a few times as ext4 with read-write test and an area did show up with maybe 30 bad blocks.  However, retesting today, i find no bad blocks at all.

So anyway I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

- If you hear strange sounds like your Hard Disk Drive  ticks like a clock.
- If your Hard Disk Drive motor spin-up slow or getting slower.

The S.M.A.R.T. report can behave like your question with the conditions above.

It's time to replace it, doesn't matter how old it is, it can be 3 weeks or 12 years.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you had around 30 bad blocks and the are gone, plus the reallocation may imply a faulty connection. Try replacing the SATA cable, then give the drive a check with any disk checking tool. Re-check SMART attributes.